# extracting information(using getters) from bean objects and rendering it on jsp

Tags: java, jsp, arraylist

I have `java.util.List` of 10 bean(bean name-ResonseBean) objects using `ArrayList` in my JSP. I have to extract information from each object and add it in HTML code on same JSP page. How can I do it efficiently?

```
List<ResponseBean> repo=new ArrayList<ResponseBean>(30);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jstl library. It is useful to render Collections in JSP.

For more [read here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSTL4.html)